# Entity Framework - Linq to Entities - strange issue with Anonymous function

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, anonymous-function

Following is the code, I am trying:

```
public List<Movie> GetMovies()
{
    Func<Movie, Movie> prepareMovieOutput = 
        (input) => 
            {
                input.DisplayHtmlContent = String.Empty;
                return input;
            };

    var moviesOutput = from m in db.Movies.ToList()
                                     select prepareMovieOutput(m);

    return moviesOutput.ToList();
}

public List<Movie> SearchMovies(string searchTerm)
{
    var moviesOutput = db.Movies.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList();                                   
    return moviesOutput.ToList();
}
```

The GetMovies function is working properly, as it returns List collection after clearing DisplayHtmlContent field, whereas, SearchMovies function is supposed to return Movie collection with DisplayHtmlContent field, but inspite of that it returns that field empty. 
If I set DisplayHtmlContent to some fixed value (like, "ABC"),both GetMovies and SearchMovies return the list with all Movie having DisplayHtmlContent field as "ABC" value. I don't understand why the function defined in one method should affect the other one. and also how to fix this issue? 
Ideally, I want GetMovies to hold all Movie with that particular field as empty string, and SearchMovies to hold all Movie with that field containing value.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was due to the use of repository. I have removed it and it started working fine. with having EF 5, I didn't need to use repository